# how to fix for the "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content' "python error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, summarization

this is the code i used.

```
n=0
link = coverpage_news[n]['href']
title = coverpage_news[n].get_text() 
article = url.read() 
article_content = article.content 
soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib'
```

but it display an erro message 
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
plse, someone,who can help me.

Comment: Can you please format your code so that it's readable ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) may help) and post your complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you feed in an html source into a BeautifulSoup object, you want to feed it in as a string. Since you already have it as a string when you use `url.read()`, so there is no need to convert that into a string with `.content`, hence the error of, there is no `content` attribute on a `str`. Simply remove that line to fix the issue.

```
n=0
link = coverpage_news[n]['href']
title = coverpage_news[n].get_text() 
article_content = url.read() 
soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: @chitown88 Pay attention for [cloudscraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599753/how-to-extract-the-coronavirus-cases-from-a-website)