# How to extract the Coronavirus cases from a website?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the Coronavirus from a website (https://www.trackcorona.live) but I got an error.

This is my code:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.trackcorona.live')
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
li = data.find_all(class_='numbers')
confirmed = int(li[0].get_text())
print('Confirmed Cases:', confirmed)
```

It gives the following error (though it was working few days back) because it is returning an empty list (li)

```
 IndexError                               
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7a09f39edc9d> in <module>
      2 data=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
      3 li=data.find_all(class_='numbers')
----> 4 confirmed = int(li[0].get_text())
      5 countries = li[1].get_text()
      6 dead = int(li[3].get_text())

IndexError: list index out of range
```

​

Comment: That means that `li` is suscriptable but there's nothing in that position. That probably means that `li` is empty, you should try to log its content and try to troubleshoot.

Comment: Have you checked the response? It's 503 status!

Comment: @GaganTK yes it is a 503 status but how to avoid it? i had a full code scraping data about the corona virus cases from the website mentioned.

Comment: @Yoda Hi, I'm actually one of the creators of the site here. Thank you for your interest in the site. We hope that you'll be gentle with your requests since our website is 100% funded through donations & grants as all of the creators are still students. If you have any questions please contact us at team@trackcorona.live

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, Actually the site is generating a redirection behind `CloudFlare`, And then it's loaded dynamically via `JavaScript` once the page loads, Therefore we can use several approach such as `selenium` and `requests_html` but i will mention for you the quickest solution for that as we will render the `JS` on the fly :)

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

html = scraper.get("https://www.trackcorona.live/").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

confirmed = soup.find("a", id="valueTot").text

print(confirmed)
```

Output:

```
110981
```

> A tip for `503` `response code`:

Basically that code referring to `service unavailable`.

More technically, the `GET` request which you sent is couldn't be served. the reason why it's because the request got stuck between the `receiver` of the request which is https://www.trackcorona.live/ where's it's handling it to another source on the same `HOST` which is [https://www.trackcorona.live/?**cf_chl_jschl_tk**=](https://www.trackcorona.live/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=)

Where `__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=` is holding a `token` to be authenticated.

So you should usually follow your code to server the `host` with required data.

Something like the following showing the `end` url:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Main():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        url = "https://www.trackcorona.live"
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        redirect = f"{url}{soup.find('form', id='challenge-form').get('action')}"
        print(redirect)


Main()
```

Output:

```
https://www.trackcorona.live/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=575fd56c234f0804bd8c87699cb666f0e7a1a114-1583762269-0-AYhCh90kwsOry_PAJXNLA0j6lDm0RazZpssum94DJw013Z4EvguHAyhBvcbhRvNFWERtJ6uDUC5gOG6r64TOrAcqEIni_-z1fjzj2uhEL5DvkbKwBaqMeIZkB7Ax1V8kV_EgIzBAeD2t6j7jBZ9-bsgBBX9SyQRSALSHT7eXjz8r1RjQT0SCzuSBo1xpAqktNFf-qME8HZ7fEOHAnBIhv8a0eod8mDmIBDCU2-r6NSOw49BAxDTDL57YAnmCibqdwjv8y3Yf8rYzm2bPh74SxVc
```

Now to be able to call the end `URL` so you need to pass the required `Form-Data`:

Something like that:

[image]

```py
def Main():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        url = "https://www.trackcorona.live"
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        redirect = f"{url}{soup.find('form', id='challenge-form').get('action')}"
        data = {
            'r': 'none',
            'jschl_vc': 'none',
            'pass': 'none',
            'jschl_answer': 'none'
        }
        r = req.post(redirect, data=data)
        print(r.text)




Main()
```

> here you will end up with `text` without your desired values. because your values is rendered via `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

That site is covered by Cloudflare DDoS protection, so the Html returned is a Cloudflare page stating this, not the content you want. You will need to navigate that by first, presumably by getting and setting some cookies, etc.

As an alternative, I recommend taking a look at Selenium. It drives a browser and will execute any js on the page and should get you past this much easier if you are just starting out.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The website is now protected with Cloudflare DDoS Protection, so it cannot be directly accessed with python requests.
You can just try this out with https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape which bypasses this page. pip package is named as `cfscrape`