# Selenium for loop iterates through entire website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape every airport and whether or not it has badges from this website:

https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/state/AL

I can easily get the airport names and the idea is to go into every row and check if a badge is available or not. But for some reason my for loop doesn't check every row, but the entire site. Chilton County airport should be "N", not "Y".

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/state/AL")
time.sleep(3)

airport_list = []
paved_runway = []

airport_row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "state-airports__airport"]')
print(len(airport_row))

for r in airport_row:
    airport_list.append(r.text)
    #print(r.text)

    try:
        badge = r.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="airport-icons"]//app-badge')
        print(r.text + ": Y")
        paved_runway.append("Y")

    except:
        print("N")
        paved_runway.append(r.text + " N")

    #print(airport_list)
    #print(paved_runway)
driver.close()
```

Comment: why do you print `r.text` ? Why not `print(badge)` ?

Comment: you have wrong intentation and you have `driver.close()` inside `for`-loop so you close it after first element.

Comment: print(badge) doesn't really return anything useful. It's just selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement. The indentation was only wrong on Stackoverflow. I fixed it.

Comment: if it return nothing useful then why do you get it ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the list of airports which have _Heliport_ badge or _Private Use_ badge or _Unpaved_ badge?

Comment: when you use `find_elements` (with `s` in `elements`) then it never raise error but return empty list so it never goes to `except` - you would have to check if list empty or if there is no element which you need.

Comment: you have to use dot `.` in second xpath to create relative xpath and search in one row. Without dot it it absolute xpath and it search in all HTML.

Comment: Cheer, @furas that worked!

Comment: `https://webapp.aopa.org/AirportsAPI/search/advanced` post json:`{"searchType":"State","searchTerm":"AL","private":true}` , parse result, forget about selenium... - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qove5.jpg

Comment: @Pedro Lobito Thanks, I must be blind. Do you know where I can find the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dot `.` at the start of second xpath to create relative xpath and search only in one row. Without dot it search in all HTML.

```
badge = r.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="airport-icons"]//app-badge')
```

`find_elements` (with `s` in `elements`) never raise error but returns empty list and you have to check if you get empty list

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')

#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/state/AL")
time.sleep(3)

airport_list = []
paved_runway = []

airport_row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "state-airports__airport"]')
print(len(airport_row))

for r in airport_row:
    #print(r.text)
    airport_list.append(r.text)

    badge = r.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="airport-icons"]//app-badge')
    if badge:
        print(r.text + ": Y")
        paved_runway.append(r.text + ": Y")
    else:
        print(r.text + ": N")
        paved_runway.append(r.text + ": N")

driver.close()
```

Result:

```
315
00AL - Epps Airpark: Y
01AL - Ware Island: Y
02A - Chilton County Airport: N
02AL - Bass Field: Y
03AL - Highland Medical Center: Y
04A - Frank Sikes Airport: N
04AL - Anniston Ahp (Anniston Army Depot): Y
05AL - Allen Stagefield Ahp: Y
06A - Moton Field Municipal: N
06AL - Brown Stagefield Ahp: Y
07A - Franklin Field: N
07AL - Tac X Stagefield Ahp: Y
08A - Wetumpka Municipal Airport: N
08AL - Little Lagoon: Y
09A - Butler-Choctaw County Airport: N
0A8 - Bibb County Airport: N
0AL0 - Huntsville Field: Y
0AL1 - Resort: Y
0AL2 - Clay County Hospital: Y
```

Comment: Pay attention for [cloudscraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599753/how-to-extract-the-coronavirus-cases-from-a-website)