How do I solve an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content' error?
I have a Json file which has Dictionary type structure. I want to get chunks of its information followed by create embeddings.
I am getting this error while I create Embeddings:
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_community.embeddings.ollama import OllamaEmbeddings

vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
                    documents=chunks,
                    embeddings_model = OllamaEmbeddings(base_url = "http://localhost:11434", model = "nomic-embed-text:latest")
                )

the error is:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'

Could anyone suggest what can be the problem and how to solve it?
Note: I want to use Open source Embeddings model (not the paid one).

Possible duplicate: Why am i receiving "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'" when trying to add my embeddings to Azure Cognitive Search.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575687/how-to-fix-for-the-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-content-pyt

@TylerH I do not think so because in the question you Tagged, is about PDF. I have asked explicitly about JSON file (Dictionary structure available).

I agree with @Urvesh as I am also having a same problem of creating a embeddings of JSON file and this is not available in the link given by TylerH
